# What log level should be used for an expected but (potentially) bad occurrence?

Tags: api, logging, api-gateway

In my team we are currently building an API gateway, where the client can authenticate themselves with an API key. Naturally the authentication may also fail, which produces a message in the log.

Should this be logged on the 'error' or on 'info'-level?

I have a couple of arguments for both, but am unsure if there is a something I'm missing or a clear convention. Google/DuckDuckGo did not yield any meaningful results.

**Arguments for the error-level:**

- The gateway is a centralized place to catch these occurrence

**Arguments for the info-level:**

- It is a regular occurrence that doesn't indicate and failure on the gateway part
- It seems more like a problem for the client than the gateway

Comment: `warning`? .....

Comment: @RobertHarvey I was so deep in my own question that I completely forgot that exists too!

Comment: Is something implied by the "`info`", etc. terms? Java? [Log4j](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4j)? What about "Trace", "Debug", and "Fatal"?

Comment: As an aside, not an attempt to answer the question, do you also have `fatal`?

Comment: @Spencer I use Slf4j, so "Trace", "Debug" and "Fatal" are available. I don't consider them valid options for this usecase though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This sounds tricky­­--and potentially like a subjective question--but I'd say using `info` should be enough, **if** this is really something outside your control (you as in the person/entity operating the process).

For example, if the authentication would fail, because a third party server can't be reached or there's some configuration error, that should be a `warning` or `error`, not just `info`. If it's the user failing to use the correct password, that's not an `error` in the system.

However, I think the more important approach here would be separately tracking/logging these failed authentication attempts and look for potential bruteforce attacks, like producing at least a warning if someone tries the wrong API key 5 times within a minute or so (in addition to locking them out for a given period of time, obviously).

Personally, I'm not a fan of having stuff outside your control that doesn't directly impact the product overall logged as `error`. That's just misleading and IMO rather annoying (and worst case it might even "shadow" actual issues).

Take Windows' Event Viewer/logging as an example: There's a whole range of events logged as `error`, even though they actually aren't critical, maybe temporary, or even something completely expected and outside the user's control. But if you check the overview, you see there's been 1 entry marked as `error` within the last 24 hours and you'd always have to double-check whether it's harmless or not. If you don't you might miss an actual legitimate error, and that's way more harmful to the system overall IMO.

Comment: I like the idea of not logging anything outside my control as an error. I think I will log wrong API-key, empty API-Key, etc. with the `info`-level. Anything that is the responsibility of the gateway (like the connection to any auth-providers) as an `error`. 
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: +1 for separating wrong key attempts to a separate log. Or, if it's structured logging (as it should be in 2022), tag it so it can be easily filtered.

Comment: Good answer.  A good thing to consider here is whether you want to take action on something.  That is, if you log things that aren't really issues as `error` then you can't really do something like fire alerts on `error`.  The key to effective logging is to focus on how the logs will be used and then structure choose your logging approach to support that.  For example, if you have retries around retrieving something from a server, you probably don't want to log an `error` until the retries are exhausted.

Comment: Does `fatal` exist in this scheme?

Comment: @Spencer, I don't see `fatal` as relevant here. It is a higher severity level than `error` and the suggestion is to use one of the least severe levels in `info`.

Comment: @UncleCarl It was more of an aside. Anyway, `fatal` is more then just a higher severity level -- it means "STOP NOW, don't exit gracefully"

Answer (score 8):

Efficient log is important, so I'll go on a bit of a tangent first.

The key insight is that logging within a component is for the benefit of the operators of said components:

- Diagnosing issues with the component.
- Taking actions to solve issues with the component.

#### Log level rule of thumb

Which log level to use:

- **Fatal**: The component is stopping due to the error.
- **Critical**: The component is crippled by the error, it will continue running in "best effort" mode.
- **Error**: The component cannot process the current unit of work further due to the error.
- **Warning**: The component's processing of the current unit of work is crippled by the error, it will continue processing in "best effort" mode.
- **Notice**: High-level messages about the component, for example to track its status, establishment (and termination) of long-term connections, etc...
- **Information**: Relatively fine-grained messages about the component. It should be possible to disable them without impacting the ability to "get a read" on the component, and their only use should be to help diagnosing issues in production.
- **Debug**: Low-level fine-grained messages used during testing to follow the processing of the component.

Depending on the framework you use, you may not have access to all these levels (and thus some coalescing will be necessary), or they may have different names.

Some examples to help along:

- Fatal: the database is down, hence the primary function is unachievable.
- Critical: the avatars' database is down, hence the experience is degraded but the primary function is still available.
- Error: attempting to save the user's data in the database failed, even though it's working for other users. Strange.
- Warning: attempting to retrieve the user's avatar failed, even though it's working for other users. Strange.

#### Warning/Error implies Action

Any log of a warning, an error, or above, should lead to an action:

- Maybe an operator needs to check the status of the network, or of another component, ...
- Maybe a developer needs to diagnose the failure, and fix a bug.
- ...

#### Warning/Error implies Actionable

And of course, this means that the logs need to be *actionable*.

In general, this means including both *solid phrasing* and *relevant pieces of data*. As a rule of thumb, a log message without any dynamic data is incomplete.

For example, you don't log "database is down", that's not *quite* helpful:

- *What type* of database were you trying to connect to? MySQL? MariaDB? PostgresSQL? Redis? If you don't tell, one will have to *guess*, and based on the technology the configuration may be stored in different places.
- *Which* database were you trying to connect to? If you don't tell, one will have to *guess* from the configuration, and maybe they'll misinterpret it.
- *What* part of the application needs to connect to that database? If you don't tell, it's not clear whether that's the main database, or the cute avatars' database, and that changes the impact tremendously.

Instead, a better message would be:

> Primary MYSQL database ({name}) unreachable at {ip}:{port}.

And ideally, the log should also contain similar NOTICE level entries for when the connection was established/terminated, so that operators get an idea of:

- *Since when* it's a problem: helps relating the problem to any infrastructure change that happened around the same time.
- Whether *before* the problem a different name/ip/port was used: helps checking whether the configuration changed, somehow.

---

Now, let's review your usecase against all this:

1. Does this indicate a problem with your component, or not? It does not seem so.
2. Is there an action you should take to solve the problem? It does not seem so.

As such, I would argue it's not your problem to solve, however you *may* still be called to assist whoever is trying to connect to solve it. According to these guidelines and this observation, your situation thus calls for Notice (if infrequent/persistent connections) or Information (if frequent/ephemeral connections).

And to help yourself, be mindful to log the relevant details: IP, keys<sup>1</sup>, etc... and a clear reason for the rejection.

<sup>1</sup> *Careful with potential secrets, you may want to "XXX" part of them as is done for credit cards so the logs cannot be used to exfiltrate them.*

Comment: I tend to think of emissibility/debug levels and notification as orthogonal to the big four prognoses.